# Find Unique Words in Oracle Table Arrays

Tags: oracle

I have three arrays.  I need to use cursors or for loops to loop through all of them and be left with three new word arrays with no duplicates.  Is there a way to remove an item in the arrays or do I need to build the arrays from scratch.

Arrays:

```
DECLARE
type word1_array is table of varchar2(80);
type word2_array is table of varchar2(80);
type word3_array is table of varchar2(80);
WordGroup1   word1_array DEFAULT word1_array();
WordGroup2   word1_array DEFAULT word1_array();
WordGroup3   word1_array DEFAULT word1_array();
BEGIN 
  WordGroup1 := word1_array('job', 'cob', 'lob', 'rob', 'cob', 'job');
  WordGroup2 := word2_array('one', 'job', 'cob', 'job', 'bon', 'one');
  WordGroup3 := word3_array('win', 'sin', 'wry', 'fly', 'job', 'job');
 -- remove the duplicates
for word in WordGroup1.values
loop
dbms_output.put_line(word);
end loop;

END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

- [`SET()`](http://psoug.org/reference/collect_func.html) to get the distinct values of a collection; and
- [`MULTISET EXCEPT DISTINCT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/operators006.htm) to get the distinct values of a collection that are not in another collection.

Like this:

```
DECLARE
  type word1_array is table of varchar2(80);
  WordGroup1   word1_array := word1_array('job', 'cob', 'lob', 'rob', 'cob', 'job');
  WordGroup2   word1_array := word1_array('one', 'job', 'cob', 'job', 'bon', 'one');
  WordGroup3   word1_array := word1_array('win', 'sin', 'wry', 'fly', 'job', 'job');
BEGIN 
  WordGroup1 := SET( WordGroup1 );
  dbms_output.put_line('WordGroup1');
  for i in 1.. WordGroup1.COUNT loop
    dbms_output.put_line(WordGroup1(i));
  end loop;
  WordGroup2 := WordGroup2 MULTISET EXCEPT DISTINCT WordGroup1;
  dbms_output.put_line('WordGroup2');
  for i in 1.. WordGroup2.COUNT loop
    dbms_output.put_line(WordGroup2(i));
  end loop;
  WordGroup3 := ( WordGroup3 MULTISET EXCEPT DISTINCT WordGroup2 ) MULTISET EXCEPT DISTINCT WordGroup1;
  dbms_output.put_line('WordGroup3');
  for i in 1.. WordGroup3.COUNT loop
    dbms_output.put_line(WordGroup3(i));
  end loop;
END;
```

Comment: Great!.  I'll have to find the documentation on that.   I also need to make them unique between each table array.  Can set work between the arrays as well so it would remove 'job' in the the 2nd and 3rd table arrays.

Comment: @RetroCoder Updated and added links to some documentation.